# access_token facebook sign up says "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, access-token

I am having some "Trying to get property of non-object" issue with facebook sign up. The server returns errors related to access_token.

i have error form line 490 and 451. on line 451 i succeed to solve it but i ve still 2 errors from line 490.

the line was fixed by changing if ( $token->access_token ) by if ( $token['access_token'] )
I think the problem is due to codeigniter.

the line 490 is the following one:

```
   private function _token_string()
    {
        return 'access_token='.$this->_get('token')->access_token;
    }
```

Here is the entire code:

```
class Facebook_Lib extends CI_Config
{

    private $_api_url;
    private $_api_key;
    private $_api_secret;
    private $_errors = array();
    private $_enable_debug = FALSE;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_obj =$CI =& get_instance();

        $this->_obj->load->library('session');
        $this->_obj->load->helper('url');
        $this->_obj->load->helper('facebook');

        $fb_api_id     = $CI->db->get_where('settings', array('code' => 'SITE_FB_API_ID'))->row()->string_value;
        $fb_api_secret = $CI->db->get_where('settings', array('code' => 'SITE_FB_API_SECRET'))->row()->string_value;

        $this->_api_url        = $this->_obj->config->item('facebook_api_url');
        $this->_api_key     = $fb_api_id;
        $this->_api_secret  = $fb_api_secret;

        $this->session = new facebookSession();
        $this->connection = new facebookConnection();
    }

    public function logged_in()
    {
        return $this->session->logged_in();
    }

    public function login($scope = NULL)
    {
        return $this->session->login($scope);
    }

    public function login_url($scope = NULL)
    {
        return $this->session->login_url($scope);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        return $this->session->logout();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->session->get();
    }

    public function call($method, $uri, $data = array())
    {
        $response = FALSE;

        try
        {
            switch ( $method )
            {
                case 'get':
                    $response = $this->connection->get($this->append_token($this->_api_url.$uri));
                break;

                case 'post':
                    $response = $this->connection->post($this->append_token($this->_api_url.$uri), $data);
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (facebookException $e)
        {
            $this->_errors[] = $e;

            if ( $this->_enable_debug )
            {
                echo $e;
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }

    public function errors()
    {
        return $this->_errors;
    }

    public function last_error()
    {
        if ( count($this->_errors) == 0 ) return NULL;

        return $this->_errors[count($this->_errors) - 1];
    }

    public function append_token($url)
    {
        return $this->session->append_token($url);
    }

    public function set_callback($url)
    {
        return $this->session->set_callback($url);
    }

    public function enable_debug($debug = TRUE)
    {
        $this->_enable_debug = (bool) $debug;


    }
}

class facebookConnection {

    // Allow multi-threading.

    private $_mch = NULL;
    private $_properties = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_mch = curl_multi_init();

        $this->_properties = array(
            'code'      => CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE,
            'time'      => CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME,
            'length'    => CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD,
            'type'      => CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE
        );
    }

    private function _initConnection($url)
    {
        $this->_ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    }

    public function get($url, $params = array())
    {
        if ( count($params) > 0 )
        {
            $url .= '?';

            foreach( $params as $k => $v )
            {
                $url .= "{$k}={$v}&";
            }

            $url = substr($url, 0, -1);
        }

        $this->_initConnection($url);
        $response = $this->_addCurl($url, $params);

        return $response;
    }

    public function post($url, $params = array())
    {
        // Todo
        $post = '';

        foreach ( $params as $k => $v )
        {
            $post .= "{$k}={$v}&";
        }

        $post = substr($post, 0, -1);

        $this->_initConnection($url, $params);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

        $response = $this->_addCurl($url, $params);

        return $response;
    }

    private function _addCurl($url, $params = array())
    {
        $ch = $this->_ch;

        $key = (string) $ch;
        $this->_requests[$key] = $ch;

        $response = curl_multi_add_handle($this->_mch, $ch);

        if ( $response === CURLM_OK || $response === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM )
        {
            do {
                $mch = curl_multi_exec($this->_mch, $active);
            } while ( $mch === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );

            return $this->_getResponse($key);
        }
        else
        {
            return $response;
        }
    }

    private function _getResponse($key = NULL)
    {
        if ( $key == NULL ) return FALSE;

        if ( isset($this->_responses[$key]) )
        {
            return $this->_responses[$key];
        }

        $running = NULL;

        do
        {
            $response = curl_multi_exec($this->_mch, $running_curl);

            if ( $running !== NULL && $running_curl != $running )
            {
                $this->_setResponse($key);

                if ( isset($this->_responses[$key]) )
                {
                    $response = new facebookResponse( (object) $this->_responses[$key] );

                    if ( $response->__resp->code !== 200 )
                    {
                        $error = $response->__resp->code.' | Request Failed';

                        if ( isset($response->__resp->data->error->type) )
                        {
                            $error .= ' - '.$response->__resp->data->error->type.' - '.$response->__resp->data->error->message;
                        }

                        throw new facebookException($error);
                    }

                    return $response;
                }
            }

            $running = $running_curl;

        } while ( $running_curl > 0);

    }

    private function _setResponse($key)
    {
        while( $done = curl_multi_info_read($this->_mch) )
        {
            $key = (string) $done['handle'];
            $this->_responses[$key]['data'] = curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']);

            foreach ( $this->_properties as $curl_key => $value )
            {
                $this->_responses[$key][$curl_key] = curl_getinfo($done['handle'], $value);

                curl_multi_remove_handle($this->_mch, $done['handle']);
            }
      }
    }
}

class facebookResponse {

    private $__construct;

    public function __construct($resp)
    {
        $this->__resp = $resp;

        $data = json_decode($this->__resp->data);

        if ( $data !== NULL )
        {
            $this->__resp->data = $data;
        }
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($this->__resp->code < 200 || $this->__resp->code > 299) return FALSE;

        $result = array();

        if ( is_string($this->__resp->data ) )
        {
            parse_str($this->__resp->data, $result);
            $this->__resp->data = (object) $result;
        }

        if ( $name === '_result')
        {
            return $this->__resp->data;
        }

        return $this->__resp->data->$name;
    }
}

class facebookException extends Exception {

    function __construct($string)
    {
        parent::__construct($string);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return "exception '".__CLASS__ ."' with message '".$this->getMessage()."' in ".$this->getFile().":".$this->getLine()."\nStack trace:\n".$this->getTraceAsString();
    }
}

class facebookSession {

    private $_api_key;
    private $_api_secret;
    private $_token_url     = 'oauth/access_token';
    private $_user_url      = 'me';
    private $_data          = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_obj =$CI =& get_instance();

        $fb_api_id     = $CI->db->get_where('settings', array('code' => 'SITE_FB_API_ID'))->row()->string_value;
        $fb_api_secret = $CI->db->get_where('settings', array('code' => 'SITE_FB_API_SECRET'))->row()->string_value;

        $this->_api_key     = $fb_api_id;
        $this->_api_secret  = $fb_api_secret;

        $this->_token_url   = $this->_obj->config->item('facebook_api_url').$this->_token_url;
        $this->_user_url    = $this->_obj->config->item('facebook_api_url').$this->_user_url;

        $this->_set('scope', $this->_obj->config->item('facebook_default_scope'));

        $this->connection = new facebookConnection();

        if ( !$this->logged_in() )
        {
             // Initializes the callback to this page URL.
            $this->set_callback();
        }

    }

    public function logged_in()
    {
        return ( $this->get() === NULL ) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->_unset('token');
        $this->_unset('user');
    }

    public function login_url($scope = NULL)
    {
        $url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$this->_api_key.'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($this->_get('callback'));

        if ( empty($scope) )
        {
            $scope = $this->_get('scope');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_set('scope', $scope);
        }

        if ( !empty($scope) )
        {
            $url .= '&scope='.$scope;
        }

        return $url;
    }

    public function login($scope = NULL)
    {
        $this->logout();

        if ( !$this->_get('callback') ) $this->_set('callback', current_url());

        $url = $this->login_url($scope);

        return redirect($url);
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $token = $this->_find_token();
        if ( empty($token) ) return NULL;

        // $user = $this->_get('user');
        // if ( !empty($user) ) return $user;

        try 
        {
            $user = $this->connection->get($this->_user_url.'?'.$this->_token_string());
        }
        catch ( facebookException $e )
        {
            $this->logout();
            return NULL;
        }

        // $this->_set('user', $user);
        return $user;
    }

    private function _find_token()
    {
        $token = $this->_get('token');

        if ( !empty($token) )
        {
            if ( !empty($token->expires) && intval($token->expires) >= time() )
            {
                // Problem, token is expired!
                return $this->logout();
            }

            $this->_set('token', $token);
            return $this->_token_string();
        }

        if ( !isset($_GET['code']) )
        {
            return $this->logout();
        }

        if ( !$this->_get('callback') ) $this->_set('callback', current_url());
        $token_url = $this->_token_url.'?client_id='.$this->_api_key."&client_secret=".$this->_api_secret."&code=".$_GET['code'].'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($this->_get('callback'));

        try 
        {
            $token = $this->connection->get($token_url);
        }
        catch ( facebookException $e )
        {
            $this->logout();
            redirect($this->_strip_query());
            return NULL;
        }

        $this->_unset('callback');

        if ( $token['access_token'] )
        {
            if ( !empty($token->expires) )
            {
                $token->expires = strval(time() + intval($token->expires));
            }

            $this->_set('token', $token);
            redirect($this->_strip_query());
        }

        return $this->_token_string();
    }

    private function _get($key)
    {
        $key = '_facebook_'.$key;
        return $this->_obj->session->userdata($key);
    }

    private function _set($key, $data)
    {
        $key = '_facebook_'.$key;
        $this->_obj->session->set_userdata($key, $data);
    }

    private function _unset($key)
    {
        $key = '_facebook_'.$key;
        $this->_obj->session->unset_userdata($key);
    }

    public function set_callback($url = NULL)
    {
        $this->_set('callback', $this->_strip_query($url));
    }

    private function _token_string()
    {
        return 'access_token='.$this->_get('token')->access_token;
    }

    public function append_token($url)
    {
        if ( $this->_get('token') ) $url .= '?'.$this->_token_string();

        return $url;
    }

    private function _strip_query($url = NULL)
    {
        if ( $url === NULL )
        {
            $url = ( empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) ? 'http' : 'https';
            $url .= '://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }

        $parts = explode('?', $url);
        return $parts[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going on with this library. On line 451 you are looking in the $token array for the values that got returned and then it goes through a very convoluted way of setting that in the CI session and then instantly call it back from the CI session.

Line 458 sets the token into the session and then on 462 they return it but by calling a method that calls a method that returns session->userdata('token').
That seems to be why its failing on 490 because it gets the value in the session data but then tries finding the data for ->access_token on top of the returned value and that does not exist.

dump out $token before line 462 and see if it is an object or an array. If it's ann array then that would explain why ->access_token on 490 does not work. If it is an object then I would change line 462 to

```
return 'access_token='.$token->access_token;
```

or whatever the dump of $token says the value of the object is (I am assuming it is access_token) and see if that works. if it does then you have to figure out why they wrote all these extra steps and what it will be used for. If not, call it good.

Facebook has a library written that is available on github that you can just drop in the library dir in codeigniter and it will work fine. I would suggest dropping this class you are using and just use the one Facebook provides. This way you can learn how to integrate with Facebook right from their developer site and if they ever change their API calls, you do not have to rewrite code; you just replace the two files in the library dir.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank for your answer and your time. I try to replace the line 462 but i still errors related to access_token.

Comment: I would just drop the official facebook sdk in the library folder and go from there. I tried a few that were supposed to make my life easier and it just added a layer of complexity. I am sorry I could not help more.